# How do I solve an optimization problem in terms of parameters for $n$ dimensions?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

In my economics class, we usually consider very simple optimization problems.

$$L(x,y,\lambda) = xy + \lambda (m-px-qy)$$
$$L_x = y - \lambda p = 0$$
$$L_y = x - \lambda q = 0$$

$$ \frac x q = \lambda = \frac y p$$

$$x = \frac {qy} p$$

$$m = p \frac{qy}p + qy = 2qy$$

$$y = \frac{m}{2q}$$

But suppose I have $$L(\Bbb x, \lambda ) = f(\Bbb x) + \lambda (m - \Bbb p \cdot  \Bbb x)$$

And then I have

$$\nabla L =0$$ 
$$\nabla f(\Bbb x) = \lambda \nabla (\Bbb p \cdot \Bbb x)$$
$$m = f(\Bbb x)$$

How do I solve this for the $n$ dimensional case? Surely I can't do it like I did the two dimensional one where I equated $\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

In the two dimension case, the gradient of $f$ was composed of two equations, one partial derivative wrt $x$ and one wrt $y$. Then $\bigtriangledown L =0$ is in fact  a ystem of three equations with three unkonwns $x$, $y$, and $\lambda $.

In the $n$ dimensional case, you would have $n$ equations  from $\bigtriangledown f (x)=0$ and one equation from $ \frac{dL}{ d \lambda}=0$. So infact you have $n+1$ equations with $n+1$ unkowns.

Usually  in such problems first  component $x_i$  is written in term of $\lambda$.
Then all are sabstituted in the las equation $ \frac{dL}{ d \lambda}=0$ to get  $\lambda$, lastly by substitution the components are recovered.